# Jquery onclick event does not work sometimes in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, onclick

I wrote a dropdown menu for my site and it works correctly in Chrome. But in Firefox sometimes not. Especially when I click too fast.
The code:

```js
   $("#menu_sor").on("click",".menu-main",function() {
 
 var nyit = true;
 if($(this).attr("nyitva") == 1) nyit = false;
     
 if(nyit)
 {
     $(this).next().slideDown();
     $(this).addClass("ca-slided");
     $(this).find(".plus").html("&uarr;");
 }
 else
 {
     $(this).next().slideUp();
     $(this).removeClass("ca-slided");
     $(this).find(".plus").html("&darr;");
 }
 $(this).attr("nyitva",(nyit?1:0));
 return;
});
```

Comment: There is no purpose for `return;` statement here. Now regarding your issue, you should better explain what do you mean by 'sometimes not(working)'? Maybe you just need to use `.stop()` regarding animation. And FYI, you shouldn't use invalid attribute `nyitva`, use instead `data-*` attribute, e.g `data-nyitva`

Comment: To solve *multiclick* issues, you could do something like `$(this).data('clicked', 'true')`, check if it is true to return, else set it to false when method finishes.

Comment: I mean once work once dont.

Comment: Can you share your HTML code ??